# How to read SAS datasets (not in sas naming convention) imported from access

Tags: sas

I have imported Access DB into SAS using Libname. 
Libname accdb 'c:\mydata\base.accdb'. All the tables in DB are now in accdb Library now. but table names in Access DB are not matching to SAS dataset naming convention. 
My question is how to read those datasets available in accdb.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Please do not open two questions with the same question.  Next time, edit the other one to be more specific if you think it's not quite explained properly.  I've closed the other one in favor of this, but in the future please do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the option VALIDMEMNAME=EXTEND.  You can then reference the members using name literals such as '00ReadMe'n .  This should work for any member (table) name that is 32 characters or shorter.  I think that for names that are too long you might just have to either rename them in Access or create views that have shorter names that you can use instead.